# When a statement is said to be single-entry/single-exit and when it isn't?

Tags: java

I am not sure if I get this well, for example, an if statement in Java is said to be single-entry/single-exit statement.
in case of its condition is true is this considered to be its single-entry point and if false is it considered to be its single-exit point?

```
if(someCondition)
   doSomething();
```

and what are the examples of **non**-(single-entry/single-exit) statements?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

One exit point method (single-exit):

```
public int stringLength(String s) {
  return s.length();
}
```

Two exit point method:

```
public int stringLength(String s) {
  if(s == null) {
    return 0;
  }
  return s.length();
}
```

Below is a quote from Martin Fowler's book *Refactoring*:

> I often find I use Replace Nested Conditional with Guard Clauses when I'm working with a programmer who has been taught to have only one entry point and one exit point from a method. One entry point is enforced by modern languages, and one exit point is really not a useful rule. Clarity is the key principle: **if the method is clearer with one exit point, use one exit point; otherwise don't**.

and an illustration of the above statement, compare the code of these two methods doing the same:

```
double getPayAmount() { 
    double result; 
    if (_isDead) result = deadAmount(); 
    else {
        if (_isSeparated) result = separatedAmount(); 
        else {
            if (_isRetired) result = retiredAmount(); 
            else result = normalPayAmount();
        };
    } 
    return result; 
};
```

and with a few exit points:

```
double getPayAmount() { 
    if (_isDead) return deadAmount(); 
    if (_isSeparated) return separatedAmount(); 
    if (_isRetired) return retiredAmount();    
    return normalPayAmount();
};
```

> Nested conditional code often is written by programmers who are taught to have one exit point from a method. I've found that is a too simplistic rule. **When I have no further interest in a method, I signal my lack of interest by getting out**. Directing the reader to look at an empty else block only gets in the way of comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

Probably an example :

```
do {


}while()
```

Or something :

```
int someMethod() throws Exception {

  try {
    someInt = someComplexOp();
    return someInt;
   }
   catch(Exception e) {
     log.error(e.getMessage(),e);
     throw e;
   }     
}
```

Also go through [this](http://msmvps.com/blogs/peterritchie/archive/2008/03/07/single-entry-single-exit-should-it-still-be-applicable-in-object-oriented-languages.aspx) article.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to think of multiple entry points with modern high-level languages what with object-orientation and abstraction and encapsulation; but it's easy to see multiple exits from a method.  For example:

```
    public static int CountCommas(string text)
    {
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
        {
            return 0;
        }
        if (text.Length == 0)
        {
            return 0;
        }

        int index = 0;
        int result = 0;
        while (index > 0)
        {
            index = text.IndexOf(',', index);
            if (index > 0)
            {
                result++;
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Its not that always we should return at one point only. In the context of checks - returning early at the very top of the function might be cleaner. However if the function has return statements everywhere, that could lead to less readability & confusion.

If you take a look at the 2 code examples provided in above answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17295767/5143994 (by Adam Siemion), i immediately can see the nesting issue. The 1st example (without multiple returns) can be written much nicer (see below)

```
double getPayAmount() {

    double result;

    if (_isDead) {
        result = deadAmount();
    } else if (_isSeparated) {
        result = separatedAmount();
    } else if (_isRetired) {
        result = retiredAmount();
    } else {
        result = normalPayAmount();
    } 

    return result; 
}
```

Another advantage of above is at the end, if you wish to add a common impact to the result you can easily add it. E.g. Consider you now want to add a 20% extra penalty to the end calculation.

```
return result * 1.2;
```

But with the multi return it'll be harder to add that common impact.